# Anonymous error in opencv (Android) and opencv (visual studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to read every pixel in first row of 256*256 image but i have no idea why the values of r, g and b in android are differnt from values given by visual studio
My requirement is fullfilled by the values i obtain from visual studio. So what is wrong with my android code that it is not giving the same values.

Visual Studio code:

```
Mat img=imread("curve1.jpg");
 Mat img2=imread("environment.jpg");
 Mat temp(img2.size(),img2.type());

 namedWindow("Image");

 for(int row=0;row<img.cols;row++){
  int r = img.at< cv::Vec3b > (0, row)[0];
  int g = img.at< cv::Vec3b > (0, row)[1];
  int b = img.at< cv::Vec3b > (0, row)[2];
  if(row==109)
   cout<<"the 126th index contains";
  cout<<"values of   "<<row<<" = "<<r<<" , "<<g<<" , "<<b<<"\n";
 }
```

Android Code:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_nextin_nextinphotofilterslib_utils_NativeFilterFunc_Curve(JNIEnv* env, jobject,
  jint width, jint height, jintArray in,jintArray inn,
  jintArray out) {

 jint* _in = env->GetIntArrayElements(in, 0);
 jint* _inn = env->GetIntArrayElements(inn, 0);
 jint* _out = env->GetIntArrayElements(out, 0);

 Mat img2(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*) _in); // for input image
 Mat img(256, 256, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*) _inn);
 Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*) _out);

 //cvtcolor(img,bgra,CV_8UC4);
 LOGE("created Mat %d   ,   %d   ,   %d",img2.rows,img2.cols,img2.channels());
 LOGE("created Mat %d   ,   %d   ,   %d",img.rows,img.cols,img.channels());
 LOGE("created Mat %d   ,   %d   ,   %d",bgra.rows,bgra.cols,bgra.channels());

 cvtColor(img,img,CV_BGRA2BGR);
 for(int col=0;col<img.cols;col++) {
  int vrr = img.at< cv::Vec3b > (0, col)[2];
  int vgg = img.at< cv::Vec3b > (0, col)[1];
  int vbb = img.at< cv::Vec3b > (0, col)[0];
  LOGE("in loop %d  =  %d  ,  %d  ,  %d  ",col,vrr,vgg,vbb);
 }
}
```

Image to read:

[image: Image to read:]

Note: the image from android is transfered to native function by following procedure

```
public static Bitmap RGBCurve(Bitmap in,Bitmap curve_gradient){
  Bitmap filteredBitmap = null;
  Bitmap bmInImg = in;
  Bitmap bmInImg1 = curve_gradient;
  int[] mPhotoIntArray;
  int[] nPhotoIntArray;
  int[] mCannyOutArray;
  Bitmap bmOutImg;
  mPhotoIntArray = new int[bmInImg.getWidth() * bmInImg.getHeight()];
  // Copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array
  bmInImg.getPixels(mPhotoIntArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0,
    bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());
  // create dummy buffer
  nPhotoIntArray = new int[bmInImg.getWidth() * bmInImg.getHeight()];
  bmInImg1.getPixels(nPhotoIntArray, 0, bmInImg1.getWidth(), 0, 0,
    bmInImg1.getWidth(), bmInImg1.getHeight());

  // create result buffer
  mCannyOutArray = new int[bmInImg.getWidth() * bmInImg.getHeight()];

  NativeFilterFunc.Curve(bmInImg.getHeight(),
    bmInImg.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray, nPhotoIntArray,
    mCannyOutArray);

  bmOutImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight(),
    Config.ARGB_8888);
  bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0,
    bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());
  filteredBitmap = bmOutImg;
  return filteredBitmap;
 }

 public static native boolean Curve(int width, int height,
   int[] mPhotoIntArray, int[] bitmap_gradient, int[] mCannyOutArray);
```

Please help me with this, i am stuck in this problem for hours

[image]

these are the values snapshot

Comment: try again, with a png file. lossy jpg compression bears a lot of surprises

Comment: The problem still persists even if i use png image file but the values of r ,g,b given by android are bit same but with lots of repetition of the same values set of r,g,b analyse the values and then difference increases.